# combine two LinkedHashMap<>() to one Map

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to Combine two Map `timeMap1` has size 17  and `timeMap2` has size 18 in `timeMap`. After combination `timeMap` has just 23 entries. How can I fix that?

**Simple key with value:**

```
apple 
[06:15, 06:45, 07:16, 07:46]
```

**I want to combine then to get this result from the entry:**

```
   apple 06:15 06:45 07:16 07:46
```

**Code:**

```
                Map<String, List<String>> timeMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                Map<String, List<String>> timeMap1   =  merge_table(timeListFirst);
                timeMap.putAll(timeMap1);
                Map<String, List<String>> timeMap2 =    merge_table(timeListSecond);
                timeMap.putAll(timeMap2);
```

Comment: I presume you have some duplicates, how do you want them to be merged?

Comment: Do you have any over lapping keys in the two maps ?

Comment: Many keys  are the same in the both. Is there any alternative to merge them to get List<String, String>

Comment: They cannot be both the same, `17 != 18` and `23 > 18`. What on earth is a `List<String, String>`?

Comment: I want to Combine the key with value to create ArrayList<String>

Comment: I literally have no clue what you are asking. Please provide a worked example.

Comment: HashMaps use hashes for keys, and putAll() will replace by default the old value with the one that's being added. If you need to control in another way the merge result you could take a look at [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038673/merging-two-mapstring-integer-with-java-8-stream-api)