# Reducing list of two level maps to a single two level map using java 8 stream operators

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of nested maps (`List<Map<String, Map<String, Long>>>`) and the goal is to reduce the list to a single map, and the merging is to be done as follow: if `map1` contains `x->{y->10, z->20}` and `map2` contains `x->{y->20, z->20}` then these two should be merged to `x->{y->30, z->40}`.

I tried to do it as follow and this is working fine.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Map<String, Long>> data1 = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Long> innerData1 = new HashMap<>();
        innerData1.put("a", 10L);
        innerData1.put("b", 20L);
        data1.put("x", innerData1);
        Map<String, Long> innerData2 = new HashMap<>();
        innerData2.put("b", 20L);
        innerData2.put("a", 10L);
        data1.put("x", innerData1);

        Map<String, Map<String, Long>> data2 = new HashMap<>();
        data2.put("x", innerData2);

        List<Map<String, Map<String, Long>>> mapLists = new ArrayList<>();
        mapLists.add(data1);
        mapLists.add(data2);

        Map<String, Map<String, Long>>  result  = mapLists.stream().flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream()).
        collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, new BinaryOperator<Map<String, Long>>() {

            @Override
            public Map<String, Long> apply(Map<String, Long> t,
                    Map<String, Long> u) {
                Map<String, Long> result = t;
                for(Entry<String, Long> entry: u.entrySet()) {
                    Long val = t.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), 0L);
                    result.put(entry.getKey(), val + entry.getValue());
                }
                return result;
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Is there any other better and efficient approach to solve this?

How to do it more cleanly if the nesting level is more than 2? Suppose the List is like `List<Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Long>>>>` and we have to reduce it to a single `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Long>>>`, assuming similar merge functionality as above.

Answer (score 4):

You have the general idea, it is just possible to simplify a little the process of merging two maps together. [Merging the two maps can be done easily with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038673/merging-two-mapstring-integer-with-java-8-stream-api):

```
Map<String, Integer> mx = new HashMap<>(m1);
m2.forEach((k, v) -> mx.merge(k, v, Long::sum));
```

This code creates the merged map `mx` from `m1`, then iterates over all entries of the second map `m2` and merges each entry into `mx` with the help of [`Map.merge(key, value, remappingFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-): this method will add the given key with the given value if no mapping existed for that key, else it will remap the existing value for that key and the given value with the given remapping function. In our case, the remapping function should sum the two values together.

Code:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Long>> result  =
    mapLists.stream()
            .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue, 
                (m1, m2) -> { 
                    Map<String, Long> mx = new HashMap<>(m1);
                    m2.forEach((k, v) -> mx.merge(k, v, Long::sum));
                    return mx;
                }
            ));
```

---

If there are more "levels", you could define a `merge` method:

```
private static <K, V> Map<K, V> merge(Map<K, V> m1, Map<K, V> m2, BiFunction<? super V, ? super V, ? extends V> remappingFunction) {
    Map<K, V> mx = new HashMap<>(m1);
    m2.forEach((k, v) -> mx.merge(k, v, remappingFunction));
    return mx;
}
```

and use it recursively. For example, to merge two `Map<String, Map<String, Long>>` `m1` and `m2`, you could use

```
merge(m1, m2, (a, b) -> merge(a, b, Long::sum));
```

as the remapping function is `Collectors.toMap`.

Answer (score 2):

Using my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Long>> result = StreamEx.of(mapLists)
        .flatMapToEntry(m -> m)
        .toMap((m1, m2) -> EntryStream.of(m1).append(m2).toMap(Long::sum));
```

The [`flatMapToEntry`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#flatMapToEntry-java.util.function.Function-) intermediate operation flattens maps into `EntryStream<String, Map<String, Long>>` which extends `Stream<Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Long>>>`. The [`toMap`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/EntryStream.html#toMap-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) terminal operation just creates a map from the stream of entries using the supplied merge function. To merge two maps we use `EntryStream` again.

Comment: The usual simpler way with StreamEx :).

Comment: @Tunaki, actually would be simpler were [JDK-8072718](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072718) implemented.