# How to add Map using lambda expression in java

Tags: java, lambda

I want to add two Map into the third map using lambda expression in java.
following is my code. can anyone let me know how to do it.

I want above two maps into third map like Mapurls=repo+data

Please suggest me solution.

Comment: What happens when you have a duplicate key?

Comment: you could iterate over the two maps : `repo.forEach((key, value) -> mapurls.put(key, value));` and `data.forEach((key, value) -> mapurls.put(key, value));` if you have the same key in repo and data, the value of data will be stored

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038673/merging-two-mapstring-integer-with-java-8-stream-api

Comment: @oliv37 What is the advantage of that over [`mapurls#putAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll-java.util.Map-)?

Comment: @bradimus nothing, he wanted to use lambda expression. BTW you can write `repo.forEach(mapurls::put);`

Comment: What is the following, can you show us the details or at least the simplified version?

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through the key, values for each and adding them to finalMap should work -

```
Map<String, String> repo = TestRailReader.appendPathToUrl(urlRepo, CoreKeywords.REPO.name());
Map<String, String> data = TestRailReader.appendPathToUrl(urlData, CoreKeywords.DATA.name());
Map<String, String> mergedMap = new HashMap<>();
repo.forEach(mergedMap::put);
data.forEach(mergedMap::put);
```

Though the solution as suggested by @Emax in comments works better for the case when you need to merge. - [Merging two Map<String, Integer> with Java 8 Stream API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038673/merging-two-mapstring-integer-with-java-8-stream-api)

Comment: You are better off calling `Map.putAll` and letting the `Map` decide how it wants to loop.